# Drawing to selected canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a page that begins with one canvas element. Using some colored buttons on the side I can add colored squares to this canvas.

Using jQuery, I have another click event that appends another canvas to the page. Tada, 2 canvas elements.

I also created a click event that adds a class of 'selected' to whichever canvas is clicked.

My struggle is, how can I draw only to the selected canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mousedown event handler you can get the id of the clicked canvas like this:

```
function handleMouseDown(e){
  clickedId=e.target.id;
}
```

Then you can target the selected canvas based on its id.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/d46ZL/

Answer (score 0):

You could also get the canvas element from the class name, as it seems you want to do, using jQuery as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="Script/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .selected {}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:600px;">
            <canvas width="600" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:600px;">
            <canvas class="selected" width="600" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var c = $(".selected").get(0);
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);       
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to include the element in the selector, but I kept it as simple as possible to illustrate selection by the class.